# Center nowrap text in a resizable div

Tags: html, css

I have a resizable sidebar menu on my website. The sidebar has a collapse animation transition when it collapses. Some of the text in this sidebar needs to be centered. The problem is if you use something like `text-align: center;` to format the text, the text shifts around when you resize its container div because the center point of the div is changing.

The best I could do to combat this was to set `white-space: nowrap;` and eyeball the left padding to manually center the text. This works great, except I have text that is generated dynamically that I have to center. This means that with this method I would have to dynamically find the length of the text and adjust the padding accordingly, which seems wrong.

It doesn't have to use the nowrap style, but is there some way to keep text centered in a div and not shift when the div is resized?

jsfiddle illustration: https://jsfiddle.net/singerbradley/dvmauj3f/28/#&togetherjs=nvnJwReUA7

## EDIT:

Let me clarify what I'm going for. I want the text in the resizing div to be centered when the div is at full width and stay in that position while the div is resized. I also want the text to appear cut off when the container shrinks (achieved here by using `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;`) instead of going to the next line. Basically, I want what is happening in the bottom box without the text moving when the container shrinks.

```css
.enhance {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

#wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

#nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrap:hover {
  width: 50px;
}

#nowrap:hover {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:500px;">
Hover over each box to see it in motion. The centered, line wrap text shifts with div resize.
</p>
<div id="wrap" class="enhance">This text has line wraps.</div>
<div id="nowrap" class="enhance">This text has no line wraps.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your edit, the way you accomplish this is to create an inner container and set it to the width of the parent. See the `<span>` inside `#nowrap` and the added CSS for the span.

```css
.enhance {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

#wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

#nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

#nowrap span {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

#wrap:hover {
  width: 50px;
}

#nowrap:hover {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:500px;">
Hover over each box to see it in motion. The centered, line wrap text shifts with div resize.
</p>
<div id="wrap" class="enhance">This text has line wraps.</div>
<div id="nowrap" class="enhance"><span>This text has no line wraps.</span></div>
```

Comment: @BradleySinger, I updated my answer given the clarification in your edit.

Comment: Marvelous! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, the text is now not shifting around..
I hope this help.

```css
.enhance {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

#nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#wrap:hover {
  width: 50px;
}

#nowrap:hover {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nowrap" class="enhance wrap">This text has line wraps.</div>
<div id="nowrap" class="enhance">This text has no line wraps.</div>
```